# Understanding proof that $E$ and $E^\ast$ are isomorphic rank $1$ bundles.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, line-bundles

I would like to prove the following:

> **Proposition**. Let $E$ be any real line bundle over $M$. Then $E$ and $E^\ast$ are isomorphic line bundles.

I have sketched what I believe works, but am having trouble filling in the "**why**".

*Proof Sketch*. Let $E$ be any real line bundle over $M$. Consider the tensor product bundle $E\otimes E$. There is an open $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $M$ such that $E\otimes E$ admits a trivialization over each $U_\alpha$ so that the corresponding transition functions $\{\{\tau_{\beta\alpha}\colon U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to\text{GL}(1,\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\}\}$ are positive. It follows that $E\otimes E$ is trivial (**why?**). Since we have the isomorphisms
\begin{align*}
    \text{Hom}(E^\ast,E)\cong(E^\ast)^\ast\otimes E\cong E\otimes E
\end{align*}
it follows that $\text{Hom}(E^\ast,E)$ is trivial. This implies $E$ and $E^\ast$ are isomorphic line bundles.

---

The line bundle $E\otimes E$ is trivial if there is a global frame. How can I use the (positive) transition functions $\tau_{\beta\alpha}$ to construct a global frame? Corresponding to the open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$, I know we also have a smooth partition of unity $\{f_\alpha\colon M\to\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Isn't $E\otimes E$ isomorphic to $E$ when of dimension $1$?

Comment: @freakish not necessarily: the Mobius band is a non-trivial rank $1$ vector bundle $E$ over the circle, with $E\otimes E$ trivial

Comment: @OP A transition function of a rank $1$ vector bundle $E$ can be though as a map $\tau_{\alpha\beta}$ with value ins $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$. The corresponding transition function for $E\otimes E$ is $(\tau_{\alpha\beta})^2$, which then takes values in $(0,+\infty)$. Therefore, $E\otimes E$ is always trivial! In other words, if on $U_{\alpha\beta} = U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}$, the gluing $\tau_{\alpha\beta}$ reverses the orientation, then $\tau_{\alpha\beta}\circ \tau_{\alpha\beta}$ preserves the orientation.

Comment: @Didier: Well, yes that is what I wrote. I am not why having such transition functions means $E\otimes E$ is trivial; that is, has a global frame.

Comment: @OP Take trivial non-vanishing sections over each $U_{\alpha}$ such that they agree on each $U_{\alpha\beta}$, chose a partition of unity, glue them together, and show the resulting section won't vanish

Comment: @Didier: I figured a partition of unity would be used, as I mentioned, but this is what I am having trouble constructing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem reduces to show the following:

> Let $V$ be a rank $1$ vector bundle over $M$.
> Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ be a locally finite open cover trivializing $V$.
> Assume that on each $U_{\alpha\beta}$, the transition function $\tau_{\alpha\beta} \colon U_{\alpha\beta} \to GL(1,\Bbb R)$ has values in $(0,+\infty)$.
> Then $V$ is trivializable.

*Proof.*
Let $\varphi_{\alpha} \colon V|_{U_{\alpha}} \to U_{\alpha}\times \Bbb R$ be the associated local trivializations.
Recall that if $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta} \neq \varnothing$, then $\tau_{\alpha\beta}$ is given by the relation
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
\varphi_{\alpha}\circ \varphi_{\beta}^{-1} \colon &U_{\alpha\beta}\times \Bbb R &\longrightarrow &U_{\alpha\beta}\times \Bbb R \\
& (x,t) & \longmapsto & (x, \tau_{\alpha\beta}(x)t)
\end{array}
$$
Let $s_{\alpha} \colon U_{\alpha} \to V$ be the local section given by
$$
s_{\alpha}(x) = \varphi_{\alpha}^{-1}(x,1).
$$
Let $\{\phi_{\alpha}\}$ be a partition of unity associated with the open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$.
Let $s = \sum_{\alpha} \phi_{\alpha}s_{\alpha}$, which is a global section.

Let us show that $s$ is nowhere vanishing.
Let $x \in M$, and let $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1,\ldots,n}$ be the finite set of indexes $\alpha$ such that $\phi_{\alpha}(x) >0$.
Then
$$
\varphi_{\alpha_1}(s(x)) = \left(x, \sum_{j=1}^n\phi_{\alpha_j}(x)\tau_{\alpha_1\alpha_j}(x)\right).
$$
Since $\phi_{\alpha_j}(x) >0$ and $\tau_{\alpha_1\alpha_j}(x) >0$, it follows that $s(x) \neq 0$.
Hence, $s$ is a nowhere vanishing section of $V$, and induces a trivialization.
Indeed, the map
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
M\times \Bbb R & \longrightarrow & V \\
(x,t) & \longmapsto & ts(x)
\end{array}
$$
is a global trivialization of $V$.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot being new to the subject. What I am not getting is how this global section induces a global frame?

Comment: @Rough_Manifolds see the edit

Answer (score 0):

By patching locally defined metrics on $E$ using partition of unity, one can assume that there is a metric (notion of length) on each of the fibers, varying smoothly as a function of the fiber.  The metric then gives a canonical identification of $E$ with $E^*$.  This works in all (finite) dimensions; there is nothing special about dimension 1.  If one wants to take into account a complex structure for example, this will no longer work (because the isomorphism will not preserve it).